# Caffe: Install modified Caffe projects on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, build, compilation, caffe

Is there any way to install/run modified Caffe projects like [SegNet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-segnet) or [FCN-Berkley-Vision](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) on Windows?

There is  [Microsoft-led project to bring Caffe to windows](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) but I'm not sure if it contains the newer iterations of the Caffe Project. this version itself works fine but when I tried to run the [FCN-Berkley-Vision](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org) project with it, there was a stack failure error and it didn't work which led me to believe that this project needs newer versions of Caffe.

I tried replacing the Windows version Caffe files with another project like SegNet (Just seeing if it could compile and build) and as expected Visual Studio couldn't build it and threw me a handful of errors.

Even if it can be built, I want to use the Python interface so tutorials like [this](https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/) are unable to resolve this problem.

It's too bad that only those who are working with Ubuntu can easily use this great project.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, It's not just Ubuntu; I'm running Caffe happily on CentOS 7 and RedHat.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooo ! This made the feeling even worse!

Comment: These are all Linux distros, but that just moves the boundary of your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look again at the branch origin/windows that you already linked, a Cmake based version of Windows Caffe was introduced recently. Give it a try, the Ninja build is faster then the VS one when compiling the cuda files

Comment: You're welcome. I thought it might not be relevant for you anymore, but maybe it' gonna be useful for someone else.